# gpg2 decryption failed: Invalid packet but no error if decrypted with gpg1

Tags: bouncycastle, gnupg

**Problem**

A message encrypted with Bouncy Castle will be decrypted with errors by gpg version 2, but w/o errors with gpg version 1.

**Questions**

- I consider a missing part in my Java code, but this time I have no clue, what is missing.
- What is the difference on gpg version 1 and version 2 here?

**Encryption of GnuPG message**

Following Java class encrypts a message as PGP encrpted message:

```
public class GnuPG {
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GnuPG.class);

  private String pgpFingerprint=null;
  private String pgpKeysize=null;

  public enum PGP_KEY_STATUS { ok, usage, expired, invalid }


  public String getFingerprint () {
    return pgpFingerprint;
  }


  public String getKeysize () {
    return pgpKeysize;
  }


  private PGPPublicKey getKey(String key) throws IOException {
    InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ArmoredInputStream aIn = new ArmoredInputStream(inStream, true);
    BcKeyFingerprintCalculator bck = new BcKeyFingerprintCalculator();
    PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(aIn, bck);
    Object o = pgpFact.nextObject();
    PGPPublicKey p = null;
    if ((o instanceof PGPPublicKeyRing)) {
        PGPPublicKeyRing publicKeyRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing) o;
        p = publicKeyRing.getPublicKey();
    }
    return p;
  }


  public String encryptPGP(String publicKey, String msg) {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 0);
    byte inBytes[] = msg.getBytes();

    ByteArrayOutputStream sendMessage;
    try {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        PGPPublicKey p = getKey(publicKey);
        sendMessage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
                new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(
                        PGPEncryptedData.AES_256).
                        setWithIntegrityPacket(true).
                        setSecureRandom(rand)
        );

        encryptedDataGenerator.addMethod(new BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(p));

        OutputStream out = new ArmoredOutputStream(sendMessage);
        OutputStream compressedOut = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZIP).open(
                encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, Constants.pgpBufferSize),
                new byte[Constants.pgpBufferSize]
        );

        PGPLiteralDataGenerator plg=new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream finalOut = plg.open(
                compressedOut,
                PGPLiteralData.BINARY,
                PGPLiteralDataGenerator.CONSOLE,
                new Date(),
                new byte[Constants.pgpBufferSize]
        );

        byte[] buf = new byte[Constants.pgpBufferSize];
        int len;
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(inBytes);
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            finalOut.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        finalOut.close();
        plg.close();
        compressedOut.close();
        encryptedDataGenerator.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("encryptPGP: all closed now");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("encryptPGP: "+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return sendMessage.toString();
  }
}
```

This small junit does a simple test to encrypt "Hello world!"

```
@Test
public void testEncryptPGP() throws Exception {
    GnuPG gpg = new GnuPG();
    String res = gpg.encryptPGP(pgpKey, msg);

    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Decryption with gpg2 ends up with infamous *Invalid packet* error, but message will be decrypted.

```
    $ LANG=C gpg2 -vvvv -d xxx.asc > xxx.txt 
    gpg: using character set 'iso-8859-1'
    gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP MESSAGE
    gpg: armor header: Version: BCPG v1.53
    # off=0 ctb=85 tag=1 hlen=3 plen=524
    :pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid ***
        data: [4096 bits]
    gpg: public key is ***
    gpg: public key encrypted data: good DEK
    # off=527 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=3 plen=4137 new-ctb
    :encrypted data packet:
        length: 4137
        mdc_method: 2
    gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID ***, created 2013-09-01
          "Hostmaster <hostmaster@example.com>"
    gpg: AES256 encrypted data
    # off=549 ctb=c8 tag=8 hlen=2 plen=31 new-ctb
    :compressed packet: algo=1
    # off=552 ctb=cb tag=11 hlen=2 plen=26 new-ctb
    :literal data packet:
        mode b (62), created 1450355926, name="_CONSOLE",
        raw data: 12 bytes
    gpg: Note: sender requested "for-your-eyes-only"
    gpg: decryption failed: Invalid packet
```

Now same with gpg version 1 - no error.

```
    gpg: using character set iso-8859-1
    gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP MESSAGE
    gpg: armor header: Version: BCPG v1.53
    :pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid ***
        data: [4096 bits]
    gpg: public key is ***

    You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
    user: "Hostmaster <hostmaster@example.com>"
    4096-bit RSA key, ID ***, created 2013-09-01

    gpg: public key encrypted data: good DEK
    :encrypted data packet:
        length: 4137
        mdc_method: 2
    gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID ***, created 2013-09-01
          "Hostmaster <hostmaster@example.com>"
    gpg: AES256 encrypted data
    :compressed packet: algo=1
    :literal data packet:
        mode b (62), created 1450355926, name="_CONSOLE",
        raw data: 12 bytes
    gpg: NOTE: sender requested "for-your-eyes-only"
    gpg: decryption okay
```